# Set maximum allowed file size for S3 multipart upload

Tags: amazon-s3, evaporate.js

You can limit file size with **content-length-range** field in a browser based upload (not multipart):
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html

How can you limit it in a multipart upload? I'm using [EvaporateJS](https://github.com/TTLabs/EvaporateJS).

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the late reply but I did know know there was an EvaporateJS thread here.

FWIW, use the `maxFileSize` option on `Evaporate.prototype.add` to validate maximum file size.